# SQL Server with C++/CLI

Tags: .net, sql-server, c++-cli

I am trying to connect to SQL Server from managed C++ code. However I cannot establish a connection with SQL Server. I connected to SQL Server from Visual Studio and copied/pasted the connection string. This connection string is also currently working for a C# application.

My code is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.dll>
#using <system.data.dll>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "SqlServer.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;
using namespace System::Xml;

bool getAllUsers()
{
    SqlConnection^ connection;
    //SqlDataAdapter^ dataAdapter;
    //DataSet^ dataSet;
    SqlDataReader^ dataReader;
    SqlCommand^ sqlCommand;

    connection = gcnew SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\OMEGA;Initial Catalog=Omega;Integrated Security=True");
    //dataAdapter = gcnew SqlDataAdapter();
    //dataSet = gcnew DataSet();
    sqlCommand = gcnew SqlCommand("select * from applicationuser", connection);

    connection->Open();

    dataReader = sqlCommand->ExecuteReader();

    while (dataReader->Read())
    {
        Console::WriteLine(dataReader->GetSqlString(0));
    }

    connection->Close();

    return true;
}
```

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash '\' is not escaped before 'OMEGA'. Try \\OMEGA .